# Why do I get an empty list if I add an "else" to my function?

Tags: python, python-3.x, if-statement, generator, yield

If I execute this piece of code I get an empty list:

```
#quick.py
def test(key): 
    print('the input key is:',key)   
    if key==1: 
        return range(1,13)
    else:
        month = ['15','30']
        for i in range(1,53):
            if i==4: 
                yield '2904'
            else:
                str_i = str(i)
                if i<10:
                    str_i= '0'+str_i 
                yield month[0] + str_i if i % 2 else month[1] + str_i

my_list = list(test(1))
print('the list is :' ,my_list)
```

```
pc@pc-host:~/Git/PasivicSerious$ python3 quick.py
    the input key is: 1
    the list is : []
```

but without the " else " I get my desired list:

```
def test(key): 
    print('the input key is:',key)   
    if key==1: 
        return range(1,13)
    # else:
    #     month = ['15','30']
    #     for i in range(1,53):
    #         if i==4: 
    #             yield '2904'
    #         else:
    #             str_i = str(i)
    #             if i<10:
    #                 str_i= '0'+str_i 
    #             yield month[0] + str_i if i % 2 else month[1] + str_i

my_list = list(test(1))
print('the list is :' ,my_list)
```

```
pc@pc-host:~/Git/PasivicSerious$ python3 quick.py
the input key is: 1
the list is : [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12]
```

Why does this happen, what am I misunderstanding about generators?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `yield` keyword, you are actually creating a "generator" not a function. As you can see in this link, (PEP-380 https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0380/) in a generator, the statement `return value` is semantically equivalent to `raise StopIteration(value)`. The point is, if you want to make a function or a generator, don't mix `yield` and `return` keyword.

Possible modification: Change the result of first `if` statement so that it does not use `return` keyword, i.e., use `yield` and manually implement the range call.